# Why does my ISP router (home) have 4 IP addresses?

Tags: router, isp

My home router (ISP rental) has 4 IPs. Is this appropriate?

My son feels this is a security risk and he would like to remove 2 of the IPs. Is there a problem, and is his advice good?

Comment: If the IP addresses are Internal (e.g. 192.168.1.x), it probably does not matter. If you have 4 External IP addresses, that would likely  be a business plan. Most ordinary users just have ONE External IP address.

Comment: Please include in your post a screenshot showing where you see these 4 IPs.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see where you see these 4 IP addresses.  A screenshot would help.

That being said, routers often have multiple IP addresses for different valid reasons.

The WAN interface (internet facing) will have a public IP address.  The LAN interface (private internal) interface will have its own IP address.  The WiFi interface might have its own IP.  Some routers have a guest interface (for guests to your house to get on the internet, but not on your personal/home network).  There may be a DMZ (demilitarized zone) interface.  There could be a VPN interface, as well.  There are *many* other reasons a router can appear to have multiple IPs.

Without more insight into what you are seeing, its impossible to say what is going on.